# Adding a second hard drive but how do I move virtuals on 2nd hard drive

Tags: virtual-machines, hard-drive, vmware-workstation

I am using VMWare Workstation 8.x. and I have 2 virtuals running under this. Now, these are on my current c: which is 54rpm very slow hard drive. and therefore VMs are really really slow as I/O is bad on that hard drive. (BTW, I have 16 gb 2100 ddr3). When vms are slow the cpu is only 5% in use and ram is halfway in used. (i dedicated 2gb on one vm active directory purpose and 8 gb on sharepoint vm)

Just got 72rpm hard drive and installed it. Now do I need to install vmware workstation 8.x on 2nd hard drive (if yes, i guess i need to uninstall the vm workstation, then reinstall it and point it to e: which is second hd)

Then copy or move the vmdk from C: to E: . then use newly installed vmware's workstation and add vmdk to this.

Not sure if this is the right planning. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to move the Workstation software itself. However a simple moving of the folders that your machine definitions reside in will suffice, then when you run workstation, use the File/open option to open your machine. You may want to remove the existing shortcut from the left pane (I think its call favorites).

Comment: Great. Let me try that.